# Jumping Physics

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

Okay so, I've been working on this Mario game for mac and I need help to get mario to jump in a curved line when up arrow and right arrow are pressed at the same time (kinda like a rainbow type of jump). I got him to jump straight by moving up and down on the y axis. Please help me make Mario run+jump. #MakeMarioJumpAgain. Thanks.

```
func jump(){
    //250 , 120
    let jumpUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: 280, duration: 0.3)
    let jumpDown = SKAction.moveTo(y: 120, duration: 0.3)
    let jumpSequence = SKAction.sequence([jumpUp,jumpDown])

    player.run(jumpSequence)
}

func userMoveRight(){
    player.xScale = 0.23
    level.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))
    background.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))
    question.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: -20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))
}

func userMoveLeft(){
    player.xScale = -0.23
    background.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))
    level.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))
    question.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveBy(x: 20, y: 0, duration: 0.2)]))

}

override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let keyCode = theEvent.keyCode

    //Moving Right
    if  keyCode == 124{
        userMoveRight()
    }

    //Moving Left
    if player.position.x <= 490, background.position.x <= 1513, keyCode == 123 {
        userMoveLeft()
    }

    //Jump
    if keyCode == 126 , player.position.y == 120 {
        jump()
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-sprite-along-path-spritekit-swift

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibezierpath/1624351-addquadcurve

Comment: Sadly, that as well as UIBezier paths don't work for OSX Sdks :( Thanks for the response though :) @0x141E

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the tag. Try this https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgmutablepath/2427128-addquadcurve

Comment: oh come on, a little research on your part could easily show that the equivalent of UIBezierPath is NSBezierPath,  you just need to be careful because I believe NSBezierPath uses degrees

Comment: @Knight0fDragon as you know, `followPath` takes a `CGPath` as one of its arguments. Unlike `UIBezierPath`, `NSBezierPath` does not have a computed property that does the conversion. You'll need to implement your own conversion routine (shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH206-SW2)) which amounts to coding it up with `CGPath` statements.